# Eclipse update site that contains apache.poi 5.0.0

Tags: eclipse, apache-poi

I need an update site that contains apache.poi 5.0.0.

I have only found the following [update](https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20210223232630/) site, but latest apache poi is 4.1.1:

(https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20210223232630/repository)

Comment: Just try Maven central, eg https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/5.0.0 ?

Comment: I have tried but I get that cannot find the update site.

Comment: You could always join the Eclipse Orbit project and add 5.0.0 to it. https://wiki.eclipse.org/Orbit/Adding_Bundles_To_Orbit_In_5_Minutes